# How to capture ng-model data with same names from table rows in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created an item table which can be dynamically increased on click of 'Add New Item'. On submission I want to capture all items(rows) info for sending it to REST service.

However in my angulajs controller, I can get only the first item (first table row) even though there are multiple rows created by clicking on 'Add New Item'.

My code:

```
<button id="btnAddNewItem">Add Item</button>
<table id="InputTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead><tr><th>Item Name</th>
    <th>COD</th>
    <th>EOT</th>
   </tr></thead>
<tbody><tr>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="item.name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="item.COD"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="item.EOT" id=></td>
    <tr>
 <tbody>
</table>
```

Logic when click on new item:

```
 function btnAddNewItem(){
        $("#InputTable tr:last").after(
                "<tr>"+
                "<td><input type='text' ng-model='item.name'></td>"+
                "<td><input type='text' ng-model='item.COD'></td>"+
                "<td><input type='text' ng-model='item.EOT'></td>"+
                "<td><img src='images/delete.png' class='btnExcluir'/></td>"+
        "</tr>");
        return false;
    };
```

angularjs code is here to get items data. This shows only the first row even multiple rows exist.

```
var myModule = angular.module('MyApp',[]);
myModule.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.items[];
    $scope.simulate = function(item) {
        $scope.items.push(item);
        alert($scope.items.length); --returns 1
    };
    });
```

I am actually binding all rows to same ng-model name.

Do we need to maintain unique ng-model names for each row column?

Comment: Please read [this question / answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) first. You will save yourself a lot of headache in the future

Comment: This question has a great answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427089/how-to-add-dynamic-row-to-a-table-using-angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the $compiler service or.. ngRepeat which is what i would use if I were you.

```
<button ng-click="addNewItem()">Add Item</button>
<table id="InputTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead><tr><th>Item Name</th>
    <th>COD</th>
    <th>EOT</th>
   </tr></thead>
<tbody><tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="item.name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="item.COD"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="item.EOT" id=></td>
    <tr>
 <tbody>
</table>



var myModule = angular.module('MyApp',[]);
myModule.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.addNewItem = function() {
        $scope.items.push({});
    };
});
```

Comment: Yes, I should use ng-repeat to get array of all rows! Thanks!