# Add multi-row items to a table with a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my model:

```
$scope.orders = [
    {
        id: 234324,
      created: '2015-05-01T13:53:25.366Z',
      orderedBy: 'John Smith',
      items: [
        {
            itemNumber: '225-3',
          count: 3,
          state: 'Sent'
        },
        {
            itemNumber: '3423-1',
          count: 1,
          state: 'Waiting from supplier'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
        id: 423423,
      created: '2015-06-01T13:53:25.366Z',
      orderedBy: 'Eva Andersson',
      items: [
        {
            itemNumber: '423-3',
          count: 1,
          state: 'Sent'
        },
        {
            itemNumber: '234-3',
          count: 3,
          state: 'Sent'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Its a list with orders where each order has an array with items.

I want to show this in table.

[image: Table with orders]

I tried do nest `ng-repeats` but it proved to be difficult with the static html syntax of a table. I think I manually have to add the subelements somehow. I'm not really sure how.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hadey1cf/4/

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, what doesn't work? I can see the fiddle is like the screenshot, what am I missing?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hadey1cf/5/  .. this is a quick and dirty, but I think it gets around your fundamental problem. Maybe you can run with it from there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add dynamic row to a table using angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427089/how-to-add-dynamic-row-to-a-table-using-angularjs)

Comment: Not a duplicate of the linked issue, and frankly I think that's pretty clear from reading the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple `tbody` so it's easy to do:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/9yjjpa5e/1)

```
  <tbody ng-repeat="order in orders">
    <tr class="active">
      <td><b>{{order.id}}</b></td>
      <td><b>{{order.orderedBy}}</b></td>
      <td>{{order.created | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in order.items">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>{{item.itemNumber}}</td>
      <td>{{item.count}}</td>
      <td><span class="label label-success label">{{item.state}}</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use nested repeats? Do your first repeat on the tbody and inside it repeat over the rows for the items:

http://jsfiddle.net/mcgraphix/kfnvLts0/1/

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Order Id</th>
    <th>Orderd By</th>
    <th>Created</th>
    <th>Item id</th>
    <th>Count</th>
    <th>State</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody ng-repeat="order in orders">
  <tr class="active">
    <td><b>{{order.id}}</b></td>
    <td><b>{{order.orderedBy}}</b></td>
    <td>{{order.date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in order.items">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>{{item.itemNumber}}</td>
    <td>{{item.count}}</td>
    <td><span class="label label-success label">{{item.state}}</span></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach if you for some reason don't want more than one tbody in your table is to use the ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end directives as shown here:

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Order Id</th>
    <th>Orderd By</th>
    <th>Created</th>
    <th>Item id</th>
    <th>Count</th>
    <th>State</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <!-- repeat will start with this but won't end with the closing tr tag
  Instead it will end at the ng-repeat-end directives closing tag. see below-->
  <tr class="active" ng-repeat-start="order in orders">
    <td><b>{{order.id}}</b></td>
    <td><b>{{order.orderedBy}}</b></td>
    <td>{{order.date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in order.items">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>{{item.itemNumber}}</td>
    <td>{{item.count}}</td>
    <td><span class="label label-success label">{{item.state}}</span></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- the outer repeat will end when this tag is closed. I'm seeting "display:none" so that it doesn't show a gap in your table -->
  <tr ng-repeat-end><td colspan="6" style="display:none"></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I think my first answer is a better way to go though since logically you have groups of content in your table which is what tbody is for. It is valid html to have more than one as the HTML DTD states:

```
<!ELEMENT table
 (caption?, (col*|colgroup*), thead?, tfoot?, (tbody+|tr+))>
```

However, it is good to understand how the ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end works as there are many cases where this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` directive.

You can find more information about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points)

Please see working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/tjaart/44hpushh/1/)

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="orders.tmpl.html">
  <h2 class="page-header">Orders-directive</h2>

  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Order Id</th>
        <th>Orderd By</th>
        <th>Created</th>
        <th>Item id</th>
        <th>Count</th>
        <th>State</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="active" ng-repeat-start="order in orders">
        <td><b>{{order.id}}</b></td>
        <td><b>{{order.orderedBy}}</b></td>
        <td>{{order.date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat-end="" ng-repeat="item in order.items">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ item.itemNumber }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.count }}</td>
        <td><span class="label" data-ng-class="{'label-success':item.state=='Sent', 'label-primary':item.state=='Waiting from supplier'}">{{ item.state }}</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    {{content}}
</script>
```