# Refresh table after $http post using angularjs, php and mysql

Tags: php, angularjs

I need to refresh the table to show newly added row after sending the data from `$http` method. Below is my working code for adding the form values to mysql table. Appreciate if anyone can help me out with the angular way to achieve this.

**JS Code:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.controller('bookmarkCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.addThis = function() {
$http({
  url: "addbookmark.php",
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  data: $.param({
    bookmarktitle: $scope.bookmarktitle,
    bookmarkurl: $scope.bookmarkurl
  })
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //refresh the table after success
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
});
}
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="bookmarkCtrl">
<input ng-model="bookmarktitle" type="text" class="form-control" required>
<input  ng-model="bookmarkurl" type="text" class="form-control">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addThis();">Submit</button>


<table class="table table-responsive">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>...</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <!-- repeat row -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <?php echo $row['bookmark_title'] ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
   <!-- repeat row -->
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: LMGTFY: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=angular+add+table+row

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add dynamic row to a table using angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427089/how-to-add-dynamic-row-to-a-table-using-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

@ismailvtl, angular is a client-side library, so typically the data would be populated through an ajax call from the client.  In order to dynamically add a row, the data has to be accessible to the controller.

```
$scope.bookmarks = [];
$scope.getBookmarks = function() {
    $http.get('/bookmarks').then(function(response) {
        // should do validation here
        $scope.bookmarks = response.data
    }
}
$scope.getBookmarks();
```

Then, in your html, it should look like

```
...
<tr ng-repeat="bookmark in bookmarks">
    <td>{{bookmark.bookmarktitle}}</td>
<tr>
...
```

Then, lastly, in your addThis() function:

```
$scope.addThis = function() {
    $http({
       url: "addbookmark.php",
       method: "POST",
       headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
       },
       data: $.param({
         bookmarktitle: $scope.bookmarktitle,
         bookmarkurl: $scope.bookmarkurl
       })
   }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       var bookmark = { 
         bookmarktitle: data.bookmarktitle,
         bookmarkurl: data.bookmarkurl
        }
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.bookmarks.push(bookmark)
        }
   }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       // handle error here
   });
}
```

Alternatively, you can assign the bookmarks array directly in the view from the php using ng-init  (something like `ng-init="bookmarks=[{bookmarktitle: 'titlea',bookmarkurl: 'urla'},...]"` with the values being supplied by php.