# How to add rows in a table with a button

Tags: angularjs, html-table

I'm having some issues on adding rows in a table using a button.

here is my HTML(note that i have 2 elements with the same custom directive, sure that works):

```
<input class="form-control" id="dispatcherPod" ng-model="pod.pod">
<exa-datepicker model="pod.startDate" required="true"disabled="true" min-mode="day"id="podStartDate"
                                format="yyyy-MM-dd" readonlydata="false"></exa-datepicker>
<exa-datepicker model="pod.endDate" required="true" disabled="true"
                                min-mode="day" id="podEndDate" format="yyyy-MM-dd"
                                readonlydata="false"></exa-datepicker>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
                                ng-click="puntualAdd()">{{'PUNTUAL_ADD' | translate}}</button>
```

here is my js:

```
$scope.puntualAdd = function (){
                    if($scope.pod.pod == undefined || $scope.pod.pod == null){
                        $scope.errorPod=true;
                        $scope.errorMessage.push("field_required_pod");
                    }
                    if($scope.pod.startDate == undefined || $scope.pod.startDate == null){
                        $scope.errorStartDate=true;
                        $scope.errorMessage.push("field_required_startDate");
                    }
                    if($scope.pod.endDate == undefined || $scope.pod.endDate == null){
                        $scope.errorEndDate=true;
                        $scope.errorMessage.push("field_required_endDate");
                    }
                    if($scope.errorMessage.length==0){
                        $scope.puntualSupply={};
                        $scope.puntualSupply.supply_code=$scope.pod.pod;
                        $scope.puntualSupply.start_date= $scope.pod.startDate.toString();
                        $scope.puntualSupply.end_date= $scope.pod.endDate.toString();
                        $scope.puntualSupply.state= "NULL";
                        $scope.insSupplies.push($scope.puntualSupply);
                    }

                }
```

and here is have the table that shows data :

```
<table class="table" ng-controller="SpotDispatcherController">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="col-order">{{'POD' | translate}}</th>
                                <th class="col-order">{{'CUSTOMER_DENOMINATION'| translate}}</th>
                                <th class="col-order">{{'VAT_NUMBER'| translate}}</th>
                                <th class="col-order">{{'START_DATE'| translate}}</th>
                                <th class="col-order">{{'END_DATE'| translate}}</th>
                                <th class="col-order">{{'STATE'| translate}}</th>
                                <th class="colf-cmd"></th>
                                <th class="col-order">{{'ERROR_DESCRIPTION'| translate}}</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody> 
                            <tr ng-repeat="row in insSupplies">
                                <td>{{row.supply_code}}</td>
                                <td>WIP</td>
                                <td>WIP</td>
                                <td>{{row.start_date}}</td>
                                <td>{{row.end_date}}</td>
                                <td>{{row.state}}</td>
                                <td class="colf-cmd">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-btn-container text-center">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                                                ng-click="deleteRecord()">X</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>{{row.state}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Note that I have previous data that is being shown in the table, and I want to add some other, but when I do that, my `$scope.insSupplies` take the data I wrote in the inputs, but doesn't show that in the table

No errors are given, not even in console, and I'm trying to achieve it without any `<a>` tag

Here is a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/eZkSCec9TkE9fJ0DhdzK?p=preview) of my code.

EDIT: instead of downvoting, you could tell me how to improve my question

Comment: Please add an example of your code in [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/)

Comment: @WilliamHampshire added

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a working example (as you can see your scope variables {{row.supply_code}} as-is in the html output)

Comment: i edited it, now it has no more compilation errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you have ng-controller twice. You only need it once on the `<body>`. Also, I changed your code so that you're passing in the value you want to use puntualAdd() function. It's better practice and overall makes more sense. Hope that helps!

HTML:

```
<body  ng-controller="SpotDispatcherController">
  <ng-form>
    <div class="form-inline">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label title="POD" for="dispatcherPod">POD</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="dispatcherPod" ng-model="pod.pod">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="puntualAdd(pod.pod)">PUNTUAL_ADD</button>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="col-order">POD</th>
              <th class="col-order">DENOMINATION</th>
              <th class="col-order">VAT_NUMBER</th>
              <th class="col-order">STATE</th>
              <th class="colf-cmd"></th>
              <th class="col-order">ERROR_DESCRIPTION</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in insSupplies">
              <td>{{row.supply_code}}</td>
              <td>WIP</td>
              <td>WIP</td>
              <td>{{row.state}}</td>
              <td class="colf-cmd">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="form-btn-container text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="deleteRecord()">X</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>{{row.state}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-form>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
  app.controller('SpotDispatcherController', ['$scope',

    function($scope) {
      $scope.insSupplies = [];
      $scope.pod = [];
      $scope.puntualAdd = function(input) {
        $scope.insSupplies.push({
          id: null,
          dispatch_id:null,
          supply_code: input,
          magnitude:null,
          stat: "NULL",
          state_desc: null,
          start_date_val: null,
          end_date_val: null,
          ext_date: null,
          aut_mod: null,
          date_mod: null
        });


      };
    }
  ]);
```

Working Code: [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/iT8eAeKvq4cgjt4kmjUy?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

If your code is working fine, and your array "$scope.insSupplies" updated successfully everything should work fine.

Check this answer it might help you: [How to add dynamic row to a table using angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427089/how-to-add-dynamic-row-to-a-table-using-angularjs/21440322#21440322)

Comment: Thanks for response, my $scope.insSupplies array is updated with the things i add(checked with debug) , but someway the view doesn't change when model changes...

Comment: In your plunker just remove the second 'ng-controller="SpotDispatcherController" ' directive on the <table> tag and it should work fine