# what is the alternative angular js code for the below jquery

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js and I have achieved this functionality using jquery code and now I want it to get converted to angularjs code

```
$("#addRow").click(function () {
    $("#myTable").each(function () {
        var tds = '<tr>';
        jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
            tds += '<td contenteditable="true"></td>';
        });
        tds += '</tr>';
        $('tbody', this).append(tds);
    });
});
```

Comment: you should describe what you want to do instead. Sometimes you can have a simple solution without any similarities with jQuery code, since DOM manipulations is not needed most of the time

Comment: The angular way to do this kind of things would be to use `ng-repeat="item in items"` in your view to construct your table rows, `items` being an array in your controller. Then to add a new table row, you would simply add a row in your controller array. You have several examples in SO for that, for example [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427089/how-to-add-dynamic-row-to-a-table-using-angularjs)